# SQLite. Не может найти столбец, хотя он есть

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

У нас есть приложение, которое добавляет заметки.
Выскакивает такая ошибка:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.notessample/com.example.notessample.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: note (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, note FROM notes ORDER BY _id DESC
```

Класс MainActivity:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //исп при запросе, например, нам из всей тбл надо 2 поля взять. 1 ключ, 2 сама запись.
    private static final String[] FIELD = {"_id",DbOpenHelper.COLUMN_NOTE};
    //константа для курсора.
    //показываем единственное поле COLUMN_NOTE.
    private static final String[] FROM = {DbOpenHelper.COLUMN_NOTE};
    //показать в нашем TextView.
    private static final int[] TO = {R.id.noteView};
    //чтобы записи были в обратном порядке.
    private static final String ORDER = "_id DESC";
    //объекты с которыми будем работать.
    EditText mInputField;
    ListView mNotesList;
    //наша база, ее создание.
    DbOpenHelper mHelper = new DbOpenHelper(this);
    //экземпляр базы данных.
    SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //инициалицируем объекты с которыми будем работать.
        mInputField = findViewById(R.id.inputField);
        mNotesList = findViewById(R.id.notesList);
        //второй параметр layout нужно создать. ctrl+q посмотреть какие параметры нужны.
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.note, null, FROM, TO, 0);
        //привязываем адаптер.
        mNotesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //
        mDb = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDb.query(DbOpenHelper.DB_TABLE, FIELD, null, null, null, null, ORDER);
        //цепляем курсор к адаптеру.
        mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);

    }

    public void onOkButtonClick(View view) {
    }
}
```

и класс DbOpenHelper:

```java
public class DbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static final String DB_NAME = "notes.db";
    //нужна для апгрейда, когда старая с новой не совпадает.
    static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    static final String DB_TABLE = "notes";
    //будет содержать имя нашей колонки.
    static final String COLUMN_NOTE = "note";
    private static final String DB_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE
                                                    //эта штука всегда нужна, это первичный ключ.
                                                    + " ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                                                    + COLUMN_NOTE + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    Context mContext;

    public DbOpenHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        //метод суперкласса лучше всегда вызывать первым
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
    }

    //создание базы данных.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
        //значение поля, на сколько оно будет большое.
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            //ключ значение поля.
            values.put(COLUMN_NOTE,"Note #" + i);
            //добавление строки.
            sqLiteDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE, null, values);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: note (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, note FROM notes ORDER BY _id DESC
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
        at com.example.notessample.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:51)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1257)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6076)
```

Comment: Поставьте точку останова перед `sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DB_CREATE);` и посмотрите как выглядит DB_CREATE

Comment: Соглашусь с @AlexanderChernin если даже Вы прописываете создание этого столбца, не значит, что он точно создан в конечной таблице. Лучше всего прикрепить скриншот, из обозревателя бд. Чтобы таких подозрений точно не было

Comment: Проблема была в этой строке, всем спасибо.
`static final String DB_NAME = "notes.db";`
Поменяла на:
`static final String DB_NAME = "notesDB";`
и все зарабтало

Comment: Проблема не в имени базы - так вы просто бросили существующую базу и создали новую. Теперь у вас в папке приложения их две. Проблема в том что вы, вероятно, запускали приложение, после изменили код хелпера, но не обновили БД повышением версии и реализацией `onUpgrade()`.